# CSS to center vertically four divs side by side inside a wrapper div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I am writing a page to show a receipt. It has the following columns:

- image of the product.
- description.
- quantity.
- price.

I created a div for the item and four divs inside for each column. I am having trouble aligning the column divs vertically (so the description, quantity and price are centered vertically with the image).

I created a little fiddle showing where I am - https://jsfiddle.net/j1dias/hpg32x7b/

I thought I could use display:inline-block and vertical-align:center, but they don't seem to be working as I expected.

I am trying to avoid using flexbox. Also I would prefer to not have to set height.

Please see below the html and the css.

Thanks.

HTML

```
<div class="checkout-item">
  <div class="checkout-item-image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354"/>
  </div>
    <div class="checkout-item-description">
      <span>Product name</span>
    <br>
        <span>Product description</span>
    </div>
    <div class="checkout-item-qty">
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="checkout-item-total-price">
        <span>$90.00</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.checkout-cart {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.checkout-item {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}

.checkout-item-image {
    width: 15%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkout-item-image img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.checkout-item-description {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkout-item-qty {
    width: 5%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkout-item-total-price {
    width: 5%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**EDIT**

I ended up following the suggestions and used flexbox. It seems that it is supported by most browsers.

I changed `display:inline-block` to `display:flexbox`.

Thank you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you wanting to avoid flexbox?

Comment: @DanMullin I am coming around to the idea of using flexbox. I wanted to avoid it at first because I was worried about compatibility. But it seems that most people are using it. :)

Comment: I’ve been writing CSS since it came out. Flexbox was life changing when it became widely supported. I still think grid layouts are a bit risky. Flexbox is solid though. Very intuitive. No need for clear fixes or weird float wizardry to make nice layouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox was designed to deal with exactly this sort of problem.

Just change `display: inline-block;` on your `.checkout-item` to:

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
```

[`display: flex` explanation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#display)

[`flex-direction: row` explanation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flex-direction)

[`align-items: center` explanation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#align-items)

### Non-flexbox solution:

Use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to match column heights:

```
.checkout-item {
    display: table;
}

.checkout-item > div {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to solve it without flexbox. Thank you for answering though. :)

Answer (score 1):

`float: left` is breaking your rules. Just remove `float: left`. Hope you this helps your problem.